# Java @Contended with class hierarchy

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8

I have a class hierarchy where each level contains some cold fields and subclasses define their own cold and hot fields:

```
@Contended
public class Base {
    final int cold1;
    final int cold2;
}

public class Sub extends Base {
    final int subCold1;
    @Contended("hot1")
    volatile int hot1;
    @Contended("hot2")
    volatile int hot2;
}
```

My questions are:

- How do I make sure `Sub.subCold1` is packed together with `Base.cold1` and `Base.cold2`?
- if both superclass and subclass define a contention group with the same name, do they get packed into the same group?

Comment: The documentation is not very clear but I found [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8012939) which I believe suggests that cold1 & cold2 will be grouped but subcold1 will be padded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@Contended` is not a general-purpose field layout mechanism; the answer to "how can I make sure..." is "you can't."  `@Contended` is a hint to the VM that you are expecting frequent concurrent access to this field, and the VM may attempt to lay things out in such a way as to reduce the incidence of false cache-line sharing.  Or it may do nothing; this is the nature of hints.